# Angular2 Routing throws out error

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to set up a module that will route the application. 
I have ended up setting all variable but it seems like I am missing something as I am getting error:
*"Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'IndexComponent'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'IndexComponent'"*
I am unsure where to look for after changing/staring/researching at my code for 2 hours now.

My code:

routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
//Components
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';


export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '',pathMatch: 'full', component: IndexComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],
  declarations: []
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { RoutingModule } from './routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './components/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    IndexComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RoutingModule,
    [AlertModule.forRoot()]
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify you have a primary outlet in your template:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

That line should go somewhere in your app.component.html file or template string.

Comment: That what was missing
Thanks for quick answer :)